# cvs autocomplete not working

Tags: auto-completion

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. When I'm on the server via Putty (ssh), the autocomplete is not working for the `cvs commit ...` or `cvs update ...`, although for other commands like nano, it's working fine.

eg, when I'm in a directory and try

```
nano cvsd<<tab>>
```

this is completed to `cvsdir/` (to be filled then with the actual filename of course)

however, when I'm in the same location and try

```
cvs commit cvsd<<tab>>
```

nothing happens. It's not completed. I tried in different locations (for folders that are cvs folders), and it's never working. When I type `cvs commit cvsdir`, it's working as expected - the directory actually is a cvs directory.

When I try `cvs upd<<tab>>`, this is completed to `cvs update`. 
I was looking at `/etc/bash_completion.d/`, but not many files are there. I tried copying the `cvs` file from an old machine (Ubuntu 10.04.4) to that directory, but nothing changed.

How an I ensure that the auto-complete works again for the cvs command?

Answer (score 1):

I was wrong - the fix below with editing /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/cvs is what fixed it for me. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

If you change the complete statement at the end of

```
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/cvs
```

to

```
complete -o default -F _cvs cvs
```

it will work again.

I didn't find out yet, how to set it outside, so it will not conflict future updates.

If entered on the command line you’ll get the error

```
bash: completion: function `_cvs' not found
```

and it will not complete the cvs command any more.